# Does loop invariant has nothing to do with termination?

Tags: loop-invariants

Consider the following program fragment:

```
var x, y: integer;
x := 1;
y := 0;

while y < x do
begin
    x := 2*x;
    y := y+1
end;
```

For the above fragment, which of the following is a loop invariant?

(A)x=y+1

(B)x=(y+1)^2

(C)x=(y+1)2^y

(D)x=2^y

(E)None of the above, since the loop does not terminate

As per my solution, the loop never seems to terminate. I came with the answer E but the D is the answer to the above questions. Isn't the loop invariant affected by the nontermination of the loop?

Comment: Do you intend some of the $2$'s to be exponents? As it stands, none of the answers, including (E), are appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, it was my mistake, I type the question wrong. You were right @RickDecker I intended the 2's to be exponents. I  apologize for that.

Answer (score 2):

The loop invariant is just a proposition which holds on each iteration of the loop (in your question, the relationship between $x$ and $y$ holds regardless, so no, it is not affected by loop nontermination). It doesn't inherently say anything about termination. It is potentially something that you can use to argue about termination.

The Wikipedia article on [correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correctness_(computer_science)) additionally describes the difference between partial and total correctness. For partial correctness, we don't require a program terminates, only that the result is correct if it is returned.